# Android Studio cannot resolve resources for custom views in layout preview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create custom compound view. This view works fine in runtime, but fails to draw itself in layout preview. To investigate this problem, i created simple compound view, here's example:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import my.testproject.coreui.R;

public class ImageWithCaption3 extends LinearLayout {

    private TextView textView;

    public ImageWithCaption3(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ImageWithCaption3(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        init();
    }

    public ImageWithCaption3(
            Context context,
            AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);

        textView = new TextView(getContext());
        LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                128,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.core_ui_gray));
        textView.setText("Test text");

        addView(textView);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F060034.
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1117)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1093)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1097)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getColorStateList(Resources_Delegate.java:258)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getColor(Resources_Delegate.java:236)
at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:958)
at android.content.Context.getColor(Context.java:610)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor(ContextCompat.java:523)
at my.testproject.coreui.widgets.ImageWithCaption3.init(ImageWithCaption3.java:45)
at my.testproject.coreui.widgets.ImageWithCaption3.<init>(ImageWithCaption3.java:32)
at my.testproject.coreui.widgets.ImageWithCaption3.<init>(ImageWithCaption3.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:401)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:184)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:142)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:229)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:421)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:432)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:336)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:327)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:386)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:450)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:590)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Project is multimodule, and view declared in library module. This library module used by every other module in app.

Constant 0x7F060034 appears in every module's R file as non-final constant, and as final 0x7f060044 in application's R file.

Also i tried to inflate some layout file inside init() method, and this layout resource also failed to resolve. I tried to clear, rebuild, invalidate caches, and reimport project. This issue repeats on other computers as well.

Android studio 3.2, gradle-4.9

I think there's a bug in resource linker in android studio layout preview, or i somehow misconfigured my project. I created this custom view in application module, and it displays fine in layout preview.

Comment: is core_ui_gray exist?

Comment: Did you try to change device of preview and API version of preview

Comment: Yes, core_ui_gray color exist, as it works in runtime fine

Comment: Yes, i tried to change device and api version in layout preview, it didn't help

Answer (score -1):

You can try it by change device of preview and API version of the preview. If it is not work for u. You can follow answers of this [Android layout previewer throws error when adding custom LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428503/android-layout-previewer-throws-error-when-adding-custom-linearlayout) .

Basically, you need to clear cache and restart your IDE to resolve it

Comment: Tried to clear, rebuild, invalidate\restart - it didn't help